# Distinguish questions and answers in reputation alerts

Tags: feature-request, reputation, top-bar

When question upvotes were worth five points and answer upvotes ten, it was immediately obvious what new reputation was for. If I saw "+5" it meant that a question got upvoted while if I saw "+10" it meant that an answer got upvoted.

Now that question upvotes are also worth ten points, the notification is exactly the same whether the upvote I received was for a question or an answer. Even if I open the pop-up I still can only see the post title. Nothing tells me whether it was for a question or an answer. Sure, in most cases I can figure it out based on the title, but there are probably times where I wouldn't remember or I've posted a self-answer.

Is there any way to have something to immediately distinguish what the reputation gain is for?

Comment: This is a sensible change but it's not a new problem, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOY0T.png).

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That would only occur if you earned reputation while away. Or a bounty.

Comment: Yes but two simultaneous upvotes on a question and one on a self answer causes the same problem leaving it unclear for what it's for. (Rare I know but was hypothetically possible).